# org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to MyUserDetails (Junit 5)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit, spring-security, junit5

I am testing web application using Junit 5, every thing working fine except

> SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()

line in controller class while running test case above code of line return object of

> org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User instead of MyUserDetails (While running application in spring boot return object is MyUserDetails and code works well)

My Test case class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(VendorController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class VendorControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/vendor/user/getVendorList").with(csrf().asHeader())
            .param("iDisplayStart","0")
            .param("iDisplayLength", "10")
            .param("iSortCol_0", "0")
            .param("sSortDir_0", "asc")
            .param("sSearch","")
            .with(user("username").password("password").roles("2"))).andExpect(status().isOk());
     }
}
```

What code I am missing so that it is return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User object while running test case using Junit 5 but working properly if I run project through spring boot.

**Adding UserDetailsService implementation code**

```
@Service("userDetailsService")

public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired

private UserSvc userSvc;

@Transactional(readOnly=true)

@Override

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.esociety.entity.UserEntity userEntity = userSvc.findByUserName(username);

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(userEntity.getUserType());

    return buildUserForAuthentication(userEntity, authorities);

}

private User buildUserForAuthentication(com.esociety.entity.UserEntity userEntity, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

     MyUserDetails myUserDetails = new MyUserDetails (userEntity.getUsername(), userEntity.getPassword(), userEntity.isEnabled(), userEntity.isAccountNonExpired(), userEntity.isCredentialsNonExpired(),userEntity.isAccountNonLocked(),authorities,userEntity.getUserId(),userEntity.getSocietyId(),userEntity.getUserType(),userEntity.getFirstName(),userEntity.getMiddleName(),userEntity.getLastName());

     return myUserDetails;

}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(String userType) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Build user's authorities

    setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userType));

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

    return Result;

}

}
```

> MyUserDetails class

```
public class MyUserDetails extends User {
 public MyUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
        boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
        boolean accountNonLocked,
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, Long userId,
        Long societyId, String userType, String firstName,
        String middleName, String lastName) {
    super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
            credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
    this.userId = userId;
    this.societyId = societyId;
    this.userType = userType;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
 }
// getter setter goes here

}
```

Comment: Do you use an implementation of `UserDetailsService` to return the `MyUserDetails`? If so, how do you make that service available to the test (as you're not loading the entire SpringApplication context)?

Comment: @AndreiDamian-Fekete I have added userDetailsService implementation code. When I login into the application buildUserForAuthentication  method is called and it creates a object of MyUserDetails which extends User, but I believe if some how buildUserForAuthentication method should get called while Junit test then I won't be getting class cast exception issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are using `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(String username)` `RequestPostProcessor` which will create and return a `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User` which is an implementation of `UserDetails` but not the `MyUserDetails` that you want.

Instead you can use `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(UserDetails user)` which allows to submit your own implementation of `UserDetails`, in this case `MyUserDetails` that you want.

Change your test as following:

```
@Test
void test() throws Exception {
mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/vendor/user/getVendorList").with(csrf().asHeader())
        .param("iDisplayStart","0")
        .param("iDisplayLength", "10")
        .param("iSortCol_0", "0")
        .param("sSortDir_0", "asc")
        .param("sSearch","")
        .with(user(new MyUserDetails ("username", "password", true, true, true,true, Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("2")),1,1,USER_TYPE,"FirstName","MiddleName","LastName")))).andExpect(status().isOk());
 }
```

Reference Spring Security [Source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/test/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/test/web/servlet/request/SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.java)

Comment: its says cast argument 1 to RequestPostProcessor or let MyUserDetails implement RequestPostProcessor `.with( (RequestPostProcessor) new MyUserDetails ("username", "password", true, true, true,true, Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("2")),2L,1L,"ROLE_2","Firstname","middlename","Lastname"))).andExpect(status().isOk());` and I am still getting same error

Comment: You can not cast MyUserDetails to RequestPostProcessor. Is your code change even runs?

Comment: It gives the compilation error if I do not cast, yes the code runs properly

Comment: few changes in code and it worked `.with( user( new MyUserDetails ("username", "password", true, true, true,true, Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("2")),2L,1L,"ROLE_2","Firstname","middlename","Lastname")))).andExpect(status().isOk());` reference [custom_UserDetails](https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/23/preview-spring-security-test-web-security#populating-a-test-user-with-a-requestpostprocessor)

Comment: `SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user(UserDetails user)` is the key for me to write integration unit tests with `@WithMockUser` for granular roles and authorities. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.